# What are the similarities and the differences between MaskGit and Diffusion models

Tags: neural-networks, transformers, diffusion

[maskgit](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.04200) and [diffusion](https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2021-07-11-diffusion-models/) - can you explain the similarities and differences between these two types of models?

Comment: For completeness it is worth adding to the question brief descriptions of both models.